# Using R to honor correlations for LatinHypercube / Monte Carlo trials

Tags: r

I am currently using python and RPY to use the functionality inside R.

How do I use R library to generate Monte carlo samples that honor the correlation between 2 variables..
e.g
if variable A and B have a correlation of 85% (0.85), i need to generate all the monte carlo samples honoring that correlation between A & B.

Would appreciate if anyone can share ideas / snippets

Thanks

Comment: I'm quite glad you asked this question as I have to do some sensitivity analysis for a project and had been looking into the theory but hadn't yet searched out R options to implement the methods I was learning about.

Answer (score 8):

The rank correlation method of [Iman and Conover](http://www.informaworld.com/index/780064783.pdf) seems to be a widely used and general approach to producing correlated monte carlo samples for computer based experiments, sensitivity analysis etc. Unfortunately I have only just come across this and don't have access to the PDF so don't know how the authors *actually* implement their method, but you could follow this up.

Their method is more general because each variable can come from a different distribution unlike the multivariate normal of @Dirk's answer.

**Update:** I found an R implementation of the above approach in package [`mc2d`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mc2d/index.html), in particular you want the [`cornode()`](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/mc2d/html/cornode.html) function.

Here is an example taken from `?cornode`

```
> require(mc2d)
> x1 <- rnorm(1000)
> x2 <- rnorm(1000)
> x3 <- rnorm(1000)
> mat <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)
> ## Target
> (corr <- matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1), ncol=3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.5  0.2
[2,]  0.5  1.0  0.2
[3,]  0.2  0.2  1.0
> ## Before
> cor(mat, method="spearman")
            x1         x2          x3
x1  1.00000000 0.01218894 -0.02203357
x2  0.01218894 1.00000000  0.02298695
x3 -0.02203357 0.02298695  1.00000000
> matc <- cornode(mat, target=corr, result=TRUE)
Spearman Rank Correlation Post Function
          x1        x2        x3
x1 1.0000000 0.4515535 0.1739153
x2 0.4515535 1.0000000 0.1646381
x3 0.1739153 0.1646381 1.0000000
```

The rank correlations in `matc` are now very close to the target correlations of `corr`.

The idea with this is that you draw the samples separately from the distribution for each variable, and then use the Iman & Connover approach to make the samples (as close) to the target correlations as possible.

Comment: Nice answer, Gavin, to an under-specified question as we were never told whether this was just multivariate Normal (or t or ...), or, as you surmise, something a little cleverer.

Comment: @Dirk Thanks - my initial inclination was to respond as you did with the `mvrnorm()` but you beat me to that one and then I wondered about this rank correlation method I had been reading about.

Comment: Thank you very much.. The cornode function does the trick! I was trying really hard to find a similar function in python

Comment: The original paper is available here: http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/STK4400/v05/undervisningsmateriale/A%20distribution-free%20approach%20to%20rank%20correlation.pdf

Answer (score 5):

That is a FAQ.  Here is one answer using a recommended package:

```
R> library(MASS)
R> example(mvrnorm)

mvrnrmR> Sigma <- matrix(c(10,3,3,2),2,2)

mvrnrmR> Sigma
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10    3
[2,]    3    2

mvrnrmR> var(mvrnorm(n=1000, rep(0, 2), Sigma))
        [,1]    [,2]
[1,] 8.82287 2.63987
[2,] 2.63987 1.93637

mvrnrmR> var(mvrnorm(n=1000, rep(0, 2), Sigma, empirical = TRUE))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10    3
[2,]    3    2
R>
```

Switching between correlation and covariance is straightforward (hint: outer product of vector of standard deviations).

Answer (score 2):

This question was not tagged as python, but based on your comment it looks like you might be looking for a Python solution as well. The most basic Python implementation of Iman Convover, that I can concoct looks like the following in Python (actually numpy):

```
def makeCorrelated( y,  corMatrix ):
    c = multivariate_normal(zeros(size( y, 0 ) ) , corMatrix, size( y, 1 ) )
    key = argsort( argsort(c, axis=0), axis=0 ).T
    out = map(take, map(sort, y), key)
    out = array(out)
    return out
```

where `y` is an array of samples from the marginal distributions and corMatrix is a positive semi definite, symmetric correlation matrix. Given that this function uses multivariate_normal() for the c matrix, you can tell this uses an implied Gaussian Copula. To use different copula structures you'll need to use different drivers for the c matrix.

Comment: Could you give an example of the usage of `makeCorrelated`? What should `corMatrix` look like? Do I need to call this twice on different `y` arrays to make the correlated?

Comment: I tried doing this as a comment, but the formatting kept messing up. So here's a gist. Note that I changed the function slightly to make it work with Pandas DataFrames:

https://gist.github.com/CerebralMastication/8039120